# Javassist, redirecting field access to object method

Tags: java, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

Hi I'm trying to use javassist to redirect all field accesses to a method of the object the field belongs to.

As of now I've written the following

```java
 private void prepareClass(CtClass clazz) throws CannotCompileException {
        CtMethod read =
                CtNewMethod.make("public void readField(Object o, String fname){ return o.getClass().getField(fname).get(o);}",clazz);

        CtMethod write =
                CtNewMethod.make("public void writeField(Object o, String fname,Object val){  o.getClass().getField(fname).set(o,val);}",clazz);

        clazz.addMethod(read);
        clazz.addMethod(write);

        for (CtMethod m: clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            CodeConverter c = new CodeConverter();
            m.instrument(new ExprEditor(){
                @Override
                public void edit(FieldAccess f) throws CannotCompileException {
                    String name = f.getFieldName();
                    if(f.isStatic())
                        if(f.isReader())
                            f.replace("$_ = $0.readField($0,\"" + name + "\");");
                        else
                            f.replace("$0.writeField($0,\"" + name + "\",$1);");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But it crashes with the following error

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] readField(java.lang.System,java.lang.String) not found in java.lang.System
```

As far as I understand is because `$0` is not referring to the actual object but to a System object.

I've both the tutorial and the documentation but I haven't found a way to refer to the effective object the field belongs to.

Does anyone of you know how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: 1) your `readField` method is declared `void` instead having an appropriate return type. 2) fields can be `static`. Then, there is no object to pass to the method. 3) The semantics of `o.getClass().getField(fname)` are different to the semantics of a field access. Due to inheritance, classes may have multiple fields with the same name and not every field is `public`. The compiler uses the compile-time type of the reference, rather than the runtime type of the object.

Comment: The error was cause by the `if(f.isStatic())` because I wanted exactly the opposite behaviour (i.e. to trigger only on instance fields), but thank you for pointing out the other mistakes.

Comment: The other problems are still applying. There’s also the issue of datatypes. I don’t know if Javassist allows conversions from `Object` to the expect field’s type without a cast, but as far as I know, it doesn’t support autoboxing, so at least conversions from or to primitive types must be done manually.

Comment: Yes I solved both the casting and boxing by explicitly adding the cast and the unboxing in the replace.